# Erase a couple lines on the screen, not clear the entire screen

Tags: c++

I'm teaching myself C++ and I came to an interesting problem in my code. How would I erase only a couple lines previously printed on the screen instead of clearing the whole screen which system("CLS") does? This isn't homework, I'm trying to teach myself and haven't found anything on this subject. Thanks!

Comment: Are you opposed to using `printf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are programming in the DOS environment, you can use gotoxy() to position the cursor upon the text you want and print some space symbols